# Trying to set up route paths, getting no route match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having big issue setting up my views.. whenever I go on my page localhost/clear I get
`No route matches [GET] "/clear".`

I have a folder named clear in my controllers with the controller files in it.

How do I set up this to be like:

```
localhost/clear as main view, 
and other one as
localhost/clear/connect
localhost/clear/test
```

base_controller.rb

```
class Clear::BaseController < ApplicationController  
    def index  
    end  
    end
```

connect_controller.rb

```
class Clear::ConnectController< Clear::BaseController

    def index 
       @functions
end
end
```

routes.rb

```
   resources :clear, only: :index
   namespace :clear do
    resources :connect, only: :index
    resources :test, only: :index
end
```

Comment: The clear module is a namespace, there is no route to it.  If clear is a resource, you could nest the other controllers like so...

       resources: :clear, as: :clear, only: [:index] do
         resources :connect, only: :index
         resources :test, only: :index
       end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the route for `/clear`

```
# routes.rb

namespace :clear do
  resources :base, only: :index, path: '/'
  resources :connect, only: :index
  resources :test, only: :index
end
```

This is how to check which routes you have

```
rake routes | grep clear
# =>
clear_base_index GET    /clear(.:format)           clear/base#index
clear_connect_index GET /clear/connect(.:format)   clear/connect#index                                                                                   
clear_test_index GET    /clear/test(.:format)      clear/test#ind
```

Comment: When I did `rakes routes | grep clear `it says clear/connect#index,` `clear/test#index` , 
I have folder in views with `clear/connect` and index.html.erb there, why it's not showing? Where exactly do I add the code you posted? Below the scope module thing?

Comment: Replace what you have with what it's in the answer. Remove your scope and add what i wrote.

Comment: What is the scope module thing for then? Will it not mess my code up if I remove it?

Comment: When I repalced it with your code I get this error: `ArgumentError at /clear
A copy of ApplicationController has been removed from the module tree but is still active!`

Comment: You are not messing up anything. 

Comment: Yes, when I do `rakes routes | grep clear` it shows `clear#index` , `clear/connect#index` so it looks fine with routing, but whenever I go on my page localhost/clear I get the error I posted above.

Comment: Hm now `NameError at /clear uninitialized constant ClearController` after restart, I edited my original post, can you please have a look?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please restart the server.

Comment: Thank you! localhost/clear works fine, but I think there is issue with the scoped thing, whenever I try to go to `localhost/clear/connect` I get this `undefined method `limit' for Users:Module`.

Comment: Before it had `scope module: :clear, as: :clear do` at start

Comment: You have to check your controller & user model to see what that error is about. It has nothing to do with the routes.